# Transition effect for side menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I am trying to get the fixed side menu bar, which opens on click of the menu.

It is working as expected, all I need now is to apply the smooth transition effect while expanding/closing it. And optimizing the jquery code, my current code is very much manual so.

Here is the script used

```
if ( $( ".sidebar" ).hasClass( "sidebar_collapsed" ) ) { 
    $( "ul.tree, .close_sidebar, .sidebar > ul > li > a > span, .sidebar_list > li > a > span" ).hide(); 
}

$( ".sidebar_list > li > a" ).click(function() {
  $(".sidebar").removeClass("sidebar_collapsed");
  $( ".sidebar > ul > li" ).removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  $( "ul.tree, .close_sidebar, .sidebar > ul > li > a > span, .sidebar_list > li > a > span" ).show();
});

$( ".close_sidebar, .home" ).click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".sidebar").addClass("sidebar_collapsed");
  $( "ul.tree, .close_sidebar, .sidebar > ul > li > a > span, .sidebar_list > li > a > span" ).hide();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1cfbn1cn/)**

Answer (score 0):

Adding `slow` to your jQuery `show` and `hide` will bring up a transition effect.

```
if ( $( ".sidebar" ).hasClass( "sidebar_collapsed" ) ) { 
    $( "ul.tree, .close_sidebar, .sidebar > ul > li > a > span, .sidebar_list > li > a > span" ).hide("slow"); 
}

$( ".sidebar_list > li > a" ).click(function() {
  $(".sidebar").removeClass("sidebar_collapsed");
  $( ".sidebar > ul > li" ).removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  $( "ul.tree, .close_sidebar, .sidebar > ul > li > a > span, .sidebar_list > li > a > span" ).show("slow");
});

$( ".close_sidebar, .home" ).click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".sidebar").addClass("sidebar_collapsed");
  $( "ul.tree, .close_sidebar, .sidebar > ul > li > a > span, .sidebar_list > li > a > span" ).hide("slow");
});
```

Also adding a css `transition` to your 'width change' would give a small animation too

```
.sidebar{
  background:#CBCAD8;
  width:180px ;
  color:#868695;
  padding:10px 8px 0 0;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:25px;
  bottom:0;
   transition: width .5s ease-in;
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1cfbn1cn/1/)

Comment: It is because of that jQuery animation. If you notice that the word `Page Link` comes in two lines for a while and then become a single line

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1cfbn1cn/8/)**

Also something with **[`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)** and **[`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)** instead of `hide` and `show` as below:

```
$( ".sidebar_list > li > a" ).click(function() {
  $(".sidebar").removeClass("sidebar_collapsed");
  $( ".sidebar > ul > li" ).removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  $( "ul.tree, .close_sidebar, .sidebar > ul > li > a > span, .sidebar_list > li > a > span" )
  .fadeIn('slow'); //fadeIn the element
});

$( ".close_sidebar, .home" ).click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active");
    $( "ul.tree, .close_sidebar, .sidebar > ul > li > a > span, .sidebar_list > li > a > span" ).fadeOut('slow',function(){
        //after completing fadeOut add the class
        $(".sidebar").addClass("sidebar_collapsed");  
    });
});
```

Comment: Its because of element position.. The `ul` inside `li` takes actual `width` and `height` once it comes into picture i.e. `display:block`. that will be `CSS` issue then..

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1cfbn1cn/9/). You can do it by adding and removing animation class.

added new class with animation `sidebar_open`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
.sidebar { 
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s linear; 
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s linear; 
    -o-transition: width 0.5s linear; 
    transition: width 0.5 linear; 
}
```

After this you only have to solve the problem with the permanent resizing ul elements.